# How to merge proguard mapping.txt of aar in other project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have an aar file which i m using in other app and aar has some proguard rules applied but whenever a crash is observed its stacktrace are in obfuscated form so how can i use my aar mapping.txt in app to deobfuscate and get proper stacktrace

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.